# dismiss a view from class extended by InputMethodService

Tags: android, view

I am created a custom keyboard. The keyboard is NOT an extension of the Keyboard class and does not use the Keyboard View class either. I have successfully created my keyboard so that it popups up. The keyboard is a LinearLayout I created from an xml file. Here is the problem: I can't get rid of it.

If it was an extension of KeyboardView, I would use

```
keyboard.closing();
```

but since its a LinearLayout, I don't have that method.

I then tried

```
keyboard.removeView(keyboard);
```

I didn't expect this to work, and it didn't.

Finally, I tried

```
keyboard.removeAllViews();
```

in hopes that it would sort of leave keyboard on the screen, but no one would no if all the views were removed. This did not work either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if `keyboard` is the View you want to hide, try calling `keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE)`. If you want to remove it entirely you would have to find the parent view of `keyboard` and call `removeView(keyboard)` on that. I think the first approach is simpler though, depending on what you want.

Comment: wow...I am a bit embarrassed I didn't think of keyboard.setVisibility(View.GONE)...Thanks